# Is it possible to determine an object being disposed right after last object reference freed up?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, destructor

I'm creating a Memory holder class that wraps around a heap object, and I want to 
determine the dispose of the object is very force for GC.

I want something like:

```
myObj = null; //Immediately call to ~myObj()
```

Comment: Finalizers are not called deterministically. You *could* force a GC with `GC.Collect`, but that will force GC to run - that's a steep penalty - don't do that (I bring it up because someone will probably recommend it). It doesn't even guarantee that you've managed to remove all strong references to the object. What you are attempting to do is very much against some of the .NET Framework's design philosophies. I would try and figure out a way to follow those philosophies rather than work against them.

Comment: Can I create a COM object? is IUnknown.Release called at last strong reference removed?

Comment: I know but I'm creating my Memory class in a small library for beginners to use and I want them to do nothing about memory garbage collection.

Comment: Do your beginners a favor and teach them the proper way to manage expensive resources: `using`/`IDisposable`.

Comment: If you defined a finalizer `~myObj()`, then you "probably did something wrong." You should ask a question concerning your actual requirements so we can help you in a way that does not require you to create (or use) a finalizer.

Comment: My memory class already implements Dispose() but also I want to do this for sure!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .NET framework and runtime provides two features for applications which use unmanaged resources.

1. **Deterministic cleanup**: The `IDisposable` interface allows code to release resources at a specific time, by explicitly or implicitly calling the `Dispose()` method. (The `using` statement in C# provides implicit support for this call.)
2. **Eventual cleanup**: In the event users fail to release unmanaged resources by calling the `Dispose()` method, a finalizer can be used to prevent long-running applications from leaking these resources over time. User code generally should not include user-defined finalizers; instead, create (or use an existing) class which extends `SafeHandle` and implement the `ReleaseHandle` method to define the release behavior.

Note that `IDisposable.Dispose()` is the **only** supported mechanism for deterministic resource cleanup. Eventual cleanup is a non-deterministic fallback that should be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do this. You should simply use [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) as it's meant to be used.

Comment: Ok I got it! , but can I create a COM object? is IUnknown.Release() called at last strong reference removed?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with COM objects, but I'd assume you can call `IUnknown.Release()` in your `Dispose` method. Take note of the pattern for managed and unmanaged resources at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx with a `Dispose(bool)` method.

Answer (score 0):

COM objects expect to be notified promptly when they go out of scope, but .NET does not support prompt notification except via `Dispose`.  You should call `IUnknown.Release` in your dispose method *but* you must ensure before calling `IUnknown.Release` that there is no way that anyone might ever try to use that COM object again.  Attempting to use a COM object that has after `Release`, or even simply trying to call `Release` upon it again, is a recipe for disaster.

I would suggest, therefore, that no reference to the COM object itself ever be released to outside code.  Instead, have the class which holds the object forward all requests to the object itself within a lock (to ensure that code doesn't attempt simultaneous accesses), and have your `Dispose` method acquire the lock, call `Release` on the object, and then *invalidate the reference*.  Any future attempts to manipulate the object which aren't otherwise trapped will cause a `NullReferenceException` which isn't brilliant, but is still way better than trying to use a `COM` object after it is released.